# Why can't I query the wordpress database from a php script?

Tags: php, wordpress

I also posted this at the Wordpress forums:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-query-post-content-with-javascript?replies=1
but no one replied, so I thought I'd try SO as well.

I'll lay out the code that I'm using in its entirety, but what it boils down to is, how do I get the content of a post from the wordpress database and replace the contents of an HTML  with that content?

At page load time, I have php that generates the post ID for the corresponding image, i.e.:
    `onmousedown="javascript:getDescription('<?php the_ID(); ?>');"`

That `onmousedown()` calls a javascript that passes the value of the post I want to query to a php file, i.e.:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function getDescription(for_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url');/>/assets/includes/get-description.php?id=" + for_id,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $('#textdescription').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>`
```

The php file get-description.php then should do the query and return the post contents, which the javascript then uses to update the `<div>` contents:

```
`<p><?php
$contentVar = $_GET['id'];
$post = get_post($contentVar);
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $title;
?></p>`
```

So this is all tested and working, except for the php file that is supposed to do the database query--- I can't get it to return anything when I query. I can return other content including my incoming post id, so I know all the pipes are connected and working.

I'm not a very sophisticated programmer, so it's probably something really simple and fundamental that I'm missing.  But I would be ever so grateful if you could help me figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: do you get any error message?  I'd be i'd be surprised if the get_post() function worked outside of the wordpress construct.

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error.  But I'm just not savvy enough with the tools at my disposal to pin that down in more detail... :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the necessary WordPress headers in the PHP file you want to make the call to `get_post()` from?

try slappin this at the top of your `get-description.php` file...

```
<?php require_once ('path/to/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');?>
```

The header should be included at the global scope (outside of any function) or you may run into some problems with WordPress thinking it hasn't been configured/installed.

You can also try following the instructions here: [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

Comment: I feel like it has to be something like this-- that post retrieval code in the php file is straight out of the codex, so clearly there's something I need to do to tell it how to handle those commands.  I tried `./wp-blog-header.php` though, and with that included the file doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your get-description.php code as part of a plugin, and then look at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for step by step instructions on how to make it all work.  Specifically, Ajax on the Viewer Facing side and 'wp_ajax_my_action', which in your case might be 'wp_ajax_get_description'.

Quick Update: Bear in mind that calls to get_post() go through all the standard filters, so you should also quickly check to see if any other plugins are affecting the call.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that the better solution here might be to not do this with ajax at all, but instead just load actual pages when the links are pressed.  I was going for minimal customization of the theme I'm using, but I think that would be better practice anyway.  But I'd like to know how to do this, for the future.